# Self-hosting a WCF service, when I try to get one error can any solve the issue

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-client

***could you provide the app.config file according to my Program class please

if possible please provide app.config code i got your point but for that what you are telling i don't know how to do***

This code is not working because it's causing an error when reaching `host.open()`. Please help me solve the issue

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Base address
        Uri baseServiceAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/Welcome");

        using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFSelfHostedService), baseServiceAddress))
        {
            // Enable MetaData publishing.
            ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceMetaDataBehaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            serviceMetaDataBehaviour.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            serviceMetaDataBehaviour.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetaDataBehaviour);

            // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. No endpoint are explicitly defined, runtime creates default endpoint.
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0} and host at {1}", baseServiceAddress, DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("The service and client is running in the same process.");

            WCFSelfHostedService selfHostService = new WCFSelfHostedService();

            Console.Write("Enter your name. : ");
            Console.WriteLine(selfHostService.WelComeMessage(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.WriteLine("Host is running... Press <Enter> key to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            //Close the service.
            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get this error:

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll*
>
> *Additional information: Service
>   'WCFSelfHostedService.WCFSelfHostedService' has zero application
>   (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration
>   file was found for your application, or because no service element
>   matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or
>   because no endpoints were defined in the service element.*

My `app.config` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
   <system.serviceModel> 
      <client> 
         <endpoint 
             address ="localhost:8090/Welcome"; 
             binding ="wsHttpBinding" 
             contract ="MyCalculatorService.ISimpleCalculator"> 
         </endpoint> 
      </client> 
   </system.serviceModel> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Which version of the .NET framework are you developing this against?

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty clear: the service has no **application endpoints** defined.

Either you have a config file that you're not showing us (if so: please **do show**!), which would configure service endpoints - or then you need to set up at least one service endpoint in code.

So either create an `app.config` file for the app where the self-hosting is happening and add something like this to it:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="YourNamespace.WCFSelfHostService" >
           <endpoint name="Default"
               address="http://yourServerName:8088/SomePlace/ServiceName"
               binding="basicHttpBinding"
               contract="YourNamespace.IWCFSelfHostService" />
        </service> 
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

or then change your code to set up at least one service endpoint in code - **before** you call `host.Open()`:

```
// Base address
Uri baseServiceAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/Welcome");

using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFSelfHostedService), baseServiceAddress))
{
   // Enable MetaData publishing.
   ServiceMetadataBehavior serviceMetaDataBehaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
   serviceMetaDataBehaviour.HttpGetEnabled = true;
   serviceMetaDataBehaviour.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
   host.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceMetaDataBehaviour);

   // Define AT LEAST one service endpoint
   host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWCFSelfHostService), new BasicHttpBinding(), baseServiceAddress);

   // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. No endpoint are explicitly defined, runtime creates default endpoint.
   host.Open();

   Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0} and host at {1}", baseServiceAddress, DateTime.Now.ToString());
   Console.WriteLine("The service and client is running in the same process.");

   WCFSelfHostedService selfHostService = new WCFSelfHostedService();

   Console.Write("Enter your name. : ");
   Console.WriteLine(selfHostService.WelComeMessage(Console.ReadLine()));
   Console.WriteLine("Host is running... Press <Enter> key to stop the service.");

   Console.ReadLine();

   // Close the service.
   host.Close();
}
```

**Update:** the `app.config` you're showing us is defininig a **client** - a program that is calling a service. What you need, however, is an `app.config` that defines the **SERVICE** side of things - see my example. You need to define one or multiple **`<services>`** in your config, which in turn expose at least one application **endpoint** where a client can connect to.

WCF is always made up of a **service** (on a server), and one (or multiple) **client(s)** calling that service. [See this article for a very basic intro to WCF architecture](http://web.archive.org/web/20070516074603/http://en.csharp-online.net/WCF_Essentials%E2%80%94WCF_Architecture). The service is configured in your config file in the `<services>/<service>` section, while your client side needs to define their stuff in the `<client>` section.

Comment: i am sharing my app.config

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address ="http://localhost:8090/Welcome"
                binding ="wsHttpBinding"
                contract ="MyCalculatorService.ISimpleCalculator">

      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>

Comment: @ankitpaul: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: could you provide the app.config file according to my Program class please

Comment: if possible please provide app.config code i got your point but for that what you are telling i don't know how to do

Comment: @ankitpaul: **look at my answer!** I show you an example of what you need in your `app.config` !!